# Permission denied while test BERT example from Google cloud shell

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, nlp

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bert/run_classifier.py", line 981, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "./bert/run_classifier.py", line 808, in main
    tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.output_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 438, in recursive_create_dir
    recursive_create_dir_v2(dirname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 453, in recursive_create_dir_v2
    pywrap_tensorflow.RecursivelyCreateDir(compat.as_bytes(path))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /MRPC-output; Permission denied
```

I am following the BERT example on the Google Cloud platform. (https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials/bert?hi)
In the last process, after input the next code, I got an error that permission denied.

```
python3 ./bert/run_classifier.py \
--task_name=${TASK_NAME} \
--do_train=true \
--do_eval=true \
--data_dir=$GLUE_DIR/${TASK_NAME} \
--vocab_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/vocab.txt \
--bert_config_file=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_config.json \
--init_checkpoint=$BERT_BASE_DIR/bert_model.ckpt \
--max_seq_length=128 \
--train_batch_size=32 \
--learning_rate=2e-5 \
--num_train_epochs=3.0 \
--output_dir=${STORAGE_BUCKET}/${TASK_NAME}-output/ \
--use_tpu=True \
--tpu_name=$TPU_NAME
```

what should I do?
Thanks for your answer in advance.

Comment: My account is trial, free.

Comment: This works fine. Please recheck all the steps from the tutorial and try again.

Comment: @KunalDeo Thanks! it works! I don know what was wrong.